# React Native Navigation with Expo

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-navigation

When using an expo managed project and running the app with expo start --dev-client I get the following error:

```
`Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNSScreenStackHeaderConfig" was not found in the UIManager.

This error is located at:
    in RNSScreenStackHeaderConfig (created by HeaderConfig)
    in HeaderConfig (created by SceneView)
    in RNSScreen (created by AnimatedComponent)
    in AnimatedComponent
    in AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by Screen)
    in MaybeFreeze (created by Screen)
    in Screen (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by NativeStackViewInner)
    in RNSScreenStack (created by ScreenStack)
    in ScreenStack (created by NativeStackViewInner)
    in NativeStackViewInner (created by NativeStackView)
    in RNCSafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProvider)
    in SafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaInsetsContext)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by NativeStackView)
    in NativeStackView (created by NativeStackNavigator)
    in Unknown (created by NativeStackNavigator)
    in NativeStackNavigator (created by App)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator
    in BaseNavigationContainer
    in ThemeProvider
    in NavigationContainerInner (created by App)
    in Provider (created by App)
    in App (created by ExpoRoot)
    in ExpoRoot
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:104:6 in reportException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:172:19 in handleException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ReactFiberErrorDialog.js:43:2 in showErrorDialog
at node_modules/expo-font/build/FontHooks.js:26:33 in loadAsync.then$argument_0

Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.`
```

When I run the project through expo go and just expo start it works perfectly.